# (Snowflake SQL) How do I collate a list of transaction keys where a customer has purchased any two out of a list of 14 or so items?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

first post here. I'm trying to obtain a list of transaction keys where any two out of a list of 14 or so products have been purchased. I've tried something like the below, but it gave me transaction keys where two products were purchased, and at least one of them was in the list:

```
create or replace temp table PIE_TRANS AS
select
case when sum(i.quantity) >=2 then i.transactionkey end as transactionkey
from ProductTable p
inner join Records i on p.productkey = i.productkey
where 
P.SKU_NO in(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14)
and i.datekey between '20200101' and '20201001'
```

It's just figuring out the correct logic :/ Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure I understand the logic needed, but try this out.

```
create or replace temp table PIE_TRANS AS
select i.transactionkey
from ProductTable p
inner join Records i on p.productkey = i.productkey
where P.SKU_NO in(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14)
  and i.datekey between '20200101' and '20201001'
group by i.transactionkey
having sum(i.quantity) >= 2
```

Comment: @AaronKing If this has helped, please feel free to uptick my answer and/or select it as the accepted answer in StackOverflow.  Happy to hear that its what you needed.